# In php form, a simple image upload to directory not working?

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

The php file for the form is:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 60000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

if (file_exists("http://example.me/imgs/examples" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "http://example.me/imgs/examples" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "http://example.me/imgs/examples" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
  ?>
```

This is straight forward enough, right? The html for the form is:

```
 <form action="img_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Filename:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

Also simple enough; correct? After submitting the image I get redirected to the img_upload.php file with the following text displayed:

```
 Upload: example.jpg
 Type: image/jpeg
 Size: 39.1943359375 Kb
 Temp file: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php66.tmp
 Stored in: http://example.me/imgs/examplesexample.jpg
```

I'm getting frustrated like mad when I attempt to do simple tasks like this and no errors but no results either. I've already attempted adding "/" like imgs/examples/ within the php script and the only difference that it made was the following line after submitting is:

```
 Stored in: http://example.me/imgs/examples/example.jpg
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing here. I have many other php scripts/mysql tables where images are being used and uploaded but for this simple task nothing. I'm using php 5 on a apache server testing on localhost. Thanks to all in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I think No upload right in your server .Check it using web site Admin panel .

Comment: Do you have the required folder for the images to be uploaded to and do you have permission to write to the directory?

Comment: I don't have admin panel. I do all the changes directly within apache's config  file, virtualhost config file, or php's ini file.

Comment: @Alex yes I have permissions, as I stated I have in other scripts for a small cms created via php/mysql where an image is being stored in a directory and it works. Also the folder for where I want the images uploaded does exist. This is why I'm frustrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that you can move a file to `http://example.me/imgs/examples/`. That's not a path on your local system.

You need to move it to a path like `C:/path/to/web/root/filename.jpg` instead.

This is different than other places where the http protocol might work because you are *writing* a file, not *reading* a file.

Your PHP script can't really know that your `http://example.me/imgs/examples/` directory is on the same server as itself; and it can't figure out that by that URL you actually mean `c:/apache/htdocs/imgs/examples/`. (Imagine if you had Apache set up to map the above directory somewhere totally different- or your file system set up to actually link that directory somewhere else! PHP can't possibly figure it out, it's just too complicated.) While it might be possible in some situations to write to an HTTP protocol URL, it's not really clear what that means, and the people who wrote PHP didn't implement that. If it were written it would probably take the form of uploading the file to that URL as a POST which would require you to write code to accept the file, and then move it somewhere on your local system... which is *exactly what you're trying to do anyway*.

Comment: preferrably using a relative pathname, or otherwise something that's at least configurable so it wouldn't have hardcoded absolute paths

Comment: It does work like this but is there a way to make this work using http request like for everything else. Like changing something in my php ini file, apache config file or some windows file of some sort. Thanks anyways for your help either way.

Comment: No. You can't save a file to an HTTP URL with move_uploaded_file(). I thought I did a pretty good job of explaining why in my answer above.

Comment: As I stated it is working using the system's local path. When I go live will I be able to change this to a relative url of serverroot or documentroot path?

Comment: The explanation that you gave did not show up until after I asked whether there was something I can do to make it work. Thanks for taking the time to explain this as it helps me to have more understanding. Much appreciated Evan.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying move your uploaded file using HTTP path (`http://example.me/imgs/examples`) which won't work.

Specify server path like `/imgs/examples/` [use the correct path, I'm just assuming]

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "/imgs/examples/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Also you may have to change below line from HTTP path to Server path,

`if (file_exists("http://example.me/imgs/examples" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))`

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is you are passing a URL to `move_uploaded_file()`. That needs to be a local file system path instead. It's the same with `file_exists()`, it can't take a URL. Example:

```
// if img directory is on the same level as the PHP script...
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "imgs/examples/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

The second problem is you don't check the return value, you simply assume the move worked. `move_uploaded_file()` returns a boolean `true` on success, or `false` on failure.

Try:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "imgs/examples/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
    // worked
}
else
{
    // didn't work
}
```

Comment: the directory is not on the same level as the php script and I did attempt to use relative urls as well. The reason also that I'm using http is because it is set up like so in my virtualhost config file for this site. I can link from one virtualhost site to another with the url like that so I don't see how this is a problem. I have it setup within my windows host file as well.

Comment: I was planning on this as a next step but figuring the image upload was/is primary. Then I would setup if else statement according to the final setup.

Comment: @Tony, there is no way to achieve that, no amount of vhost or windows host config can do it unfortunately. If you need to share the images then someting like a central place or just storing them on one of the sites will work if you pass the path to the target site e.g. `/home/sites/site-A/images/`.

Comment: thanks I now do have a better understanding. I do appreciate your time and everyone else who gave assistance as well.

Answer (score 1):

you must use a directory location system for upload.
firstyl; don't use a http:// ! 
secondary: it can be located some directory for example;
we want upload 
uploads/ dir on our .php file path

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"../uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: http request work on my setup works for everything else. Linking from one site to another, linking images from one site to another, linking stylesheets from one to another, javascripts, etc, and so forth. So why should this be any different. As I stated before windows host file and my apache config files is setup to work like this. Why would this be any different?

Comment: It's different because in the other places you're *reading from* an http path, and in this case you're *writing to* an http path. PHP doesn't know how to do that. Just try it with a file path and see if it works.

Comment: I'm just having a problem seeing as to how everything else works with http request but this and  only this I have have to use windows system paths. It would be helpful for my learning if someone could explain this. I'm going to attempt the windows local path but it seems odd to me still for this sitaution. I'd love to know why?

Comment: PHP just doesn't know how to write to a http address. I'll expand on this in my answer above, just a minute.

Comment: @Tony you can't use ".","..","..." ? They can find your directory on your host !